# Evaluate lim $a_n$, $a_n=\frac{3^n}{n!}$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I've come here as I need some help.

> I have to  find $\lim_{x\to \infty}a_{n}$,
>   where $a_{n}=\frac{3^n}{n!}$

I've tried to use Squeeze theorem ,but I couldn't find another two strings that are lower and bigger than $a_{n}$ and have the same limit.

I can consider $a_{n}\leq3^n,$ which has $\lim_{n\to \infty}3^n=\infty$,but maybe there is another proof for this exercise.

I've thought that $$\frac{3^n}{n!}=\frac{3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdots3}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n}$$ but again,I do not know how to handle it.

Please give me some advice.

Comment: *Hint:* eventually $n \geq 3^2$.  *Extended hint:* $a_{n+1}=\frac{3}{(n+1)}\cdot a_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n!$ grows faster than any fixed exponential.  One way to show it in your case is that for $n \gt 6, \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \lt \frac 12$ so $a_n \lt a_6 \frac 1{2^{n-6}} \to 0$

Comment: @Raptor:  Yes, the underscore somehow disappeared.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{3^n}{n!}=\frac{3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdots\cdot3}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\cdots n} =3\dfrac{3}{1}\dfrac{3}{2}\dfrac{3}{3}\dfrac{3}{4}\cdots\dfrac{3}{n-1}\dfrac{1}{n}<3\dfrac{3}{1}\dfrac{3}{2}1.1\cdots1\dfrac{1}{n}=\color{blue}{\dfrac{27}{2n}}$$

Comment: Sir,I have a question related to your answer.Why after $3/2$, the sequence is equal to 1?Are there some reductions that I cannot see?

Comment: $\dfrac33=1, \dfrac34<1, \dfrac35<1, \cdots, \dfrac{3}{n-1}<1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that for $n\geq 3$,
$$\frac{3^n}{n!}=\frac{\overbrace{3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdots 3}^{n}}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdot 4\cdots n}=
\frac{3\cdot 3}{1\cdot 2}\cdot \overbrace{\frac{3}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{4} \cdots \frac{3}{n-1}}^{n-3}\cdot \frac {3}{n}\leq \frac{3\cdot 3}{1\cdot 2 }\cdot \frac {3}{n}.$$
In a similar way, for any $a>0$, for $n\geq a$,
$$\frac{a^n}{n!}\leq \frac{a^{\lfloor a\rfloor+1}}{\lfloor a\rfloor!}\cdot \frac{1}{n}.$$